# What should the graph of $x=n$ or $y=n$ for any constant real $n$ look like?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

Online calculators draw the graphs either as a vertical line in cases where there is a univariate linear equation in the variable $x$ and a horizontal line when the variable is $y$.

I don't understand how this is true, after all any univariate linear equation only provides data for a single coordinate ($x$ or $y$, but not both.)

Shouldn't the graph be a single point on either $x$ or $y$ axis? Is it a convention in maths to assume the coordinate for which no data is supplied by the equation may take any real value hence the vertical or horizontal line graphs?

Comment: $x=n$ gives all points $(n,y)$ while $y=n$ gives all points $(x,n)$

Comment: What do you understand by the idea of plotting a graph?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I understand that that's the idea. But it does not seem to me that obvious that that's actually how the given equation should be interpreted mathematically.

Comment: If you think of a graph as the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying a given condition, it makes sense; the graph of $y=x^2$ is the set of all points $(u,v)$ where $u$ and $v$ satisfy $u=v^2$. The graph of $y=n$ is the set of all points $(u,v)$ satisfying $v=n$. The graph of $x^2+y^2=1$...and so on.

Comment: @ChrisLewis What I understand is, we either have a function or an equation that provides data pertaining to (both of) the coordinates of points on the real plane and thereby we are able to draw the graph. In the case where we have univariate linear equations, we only have the coordinates for one of the axes and no explicit information as to what the other coordinate should be.

Comment: In fact there is absolutely no constraint on the other coordinate.

Comment: @Kandinskij I think I'm starting to understand the idea. In my first thought process I assumed since we have x=n the graph must be the point on x axis where n is located but now that I think of it, thats actually more flawed because that implies the y value is 0, something that's obviously not implied by the equation. So when we have data for only one coordinate, we take the graph to be the set of all points that satisfy the conditions set by the equation, even when it does not say anything about a given coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, yes. There's essentially two criteria implied by an equation. You are looking at the full "universe" of the system you are working in that satisfies the criterion set up by the equation. The combination of the criteria implies more than just the single point.

For example. $y=x$ means all ordered pairs satisfying the criterion, i.e. $E_1=\{(x,y) \in R \times R|y=x\}$

In two dimensions $x^2+y^2=1$ means $E_2=\{ (x,y) \in R \times R| x^2+y^2=1\}$, a circle.  A circle in the xy plane.

In three dimensions, the same equation means $E_3=\{(x,y,z)\in R \times R \times R| x^2+y^2=1\}$. Since the criterion only specifies a relationship between $x$ and $y$, then $z$ can be anything to satisfy it. So this is a cylinder and $E_2 \subset E_3$.

Answer (score 0):

$x=n$ is equivalent to $x=n.(y^0)$. The equation $x=n$ defines a line passing through all the points of the form $(n,y)$. It does give information about the other co-ordinate $y$ that it is not bounded (above & below) or simply $sup(y) = \infty,inf(y) = -\infty$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).